# Multiple conditions within a scope rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to write a scope which will get data from two models, haven't done this before, so looking to see if anyone can help me with the theory and the practical.

My two models are defined like so

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :membership
accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership

attr_accessible :membership_id, :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street, :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email, :start_date, :expiry_date
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
attr_accessible :membership_type, :cost 
end
```

I would like to get all the members who have joined today collating the total amount in £ it has generated

So can i perform a sum in a scope or would i have to write a method that gets the total and then use that method within the scope?

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

scope :new_memberships_cash_today, ->() {
where(:start_date => Date.today)
}

end
```

That's as far as i have got so far, not correct I know .Really not sure how to construct the rest, any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume something like that will suffice:

```
joins(:memberships).where(:start_date => Date.today).sum('memberships.cost')
```

Comment: ah i see, thanks, though i get undefined method `to_key' as the value is stored as a float not an integer..any ideas?

Comment: What database do you use? MySQL, Postgres?

Comment: I have a feeling that you use wrong column type, because this suppose to work. But as an ugly alternative, you can try something like that: `joins(:memberships).where(:start_date => Date.today).select('memberships.cost').map(&:cost).inject(:+)` or `.select('ROUND(SUM(memberships.cost), 2)')`

Comment: well i was thinking about the column type, i use values such as 17.99 and 19.99, so an integer would round these numbers down wouldn't they?

Comment: Use decimal(5,2) or something like that :)